# Appending HTML-encoded string as HTML, not as text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I'm trying to append this string:

```
&lt;div&gt; hello &lt;/div&gt;
```

as an HTML node, but instead of appending HTML it just appends the text:

```
<div> hello </div>
```

How do I make jQuery append this as an HTML node, not just text?

I'd like a solution that works both for nested divs AND text, if possible.

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: That is because it has to be <div> hello </div>

Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
// This is your string :)
var myString = "&lt;div&gt; hello &lt;/div&gt;";

// This is a way to "htmlDecode" your string... see link below for details.    
myString = $("<div />").html(myString).text();

// This is appending the html code to your div (which you don't have an ID for :P)
$("#TheDivIWantToChange").append(myString);
```

[HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding)

Comment: What happens if there is complex nested divs inside the outer div instead of just the text "hello"?

Comment: Is there a way to register the new html as a jquery node so it can be referenced as such (like with $('#newDiv' )?

Comment: Thanks!! That Saved Me! Btw I used to to append text  dynamically in jquery cleditor http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new div with `.createElement('div')`. Then simply change the new element's HTML.

```
$(document.createElement('div').html('<p>All new content.</p>'));
```

To attach the new element to the DOM either use `element.append()` or `.appendTo(element)` to append to your element of choice.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is a bit verbose, but this is usually how I handle stuff like that:

```
var div = $(document.createElement("div"));

div.text(" hello "); //Or div.html(" hello ") if need be...

$("#divtoappendto").append(div);
```

Comment: curiously this answer helped me find what I needed although it may not be the very correct answer to this specific question, coming here from googling. the difference of `x.text(...)` and `x.html('...')` (where `x.append('...')` encodes like `html(...)`) I see as quite important for my problem (appending without encoding to some `<pre><code>...` node).