# JQuery: Dynamically-created html not responding to JQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this code to generate a div dynamically:

```
// my html string :)
var myString = '&lt;id="newDiv"div&gt; hello &lt;/div&gt;';

// html decode the string    
myString = $("<div />").html(myString).text();

// appending the string
$("#parentDiv").append(myString);
```

It appends just fine (it shows up on the screen). And also doing $('#newDiv').length correctly shows a value of 1. But then when I try to call remove() on it (or any function) like

```
$('#newDiv').remove()
```

nothing happens. What is going on?

Answer (score 3):

there is a bit of extra work there.  and the `&lt;id="newDiv"div&gt; hello &lt;/div&gt;` is actually `<id="newDiv"div> hello </div>`  which is not normal html to my understanding.

```
//here is what I think you wanted:
    $('<div id="newDiv">hello</div>').appendTo("#parentDiv");
    alert($("#newDiv").length);
    $("#newDiv").remove();
```

---

edit - decode the html text, then attach it:

```
var emptyDivNeverAppendedToDom = $('<div/>');
//per the other so.com question
    var html = emptyDivNeverAppendedToDom.html('&lt;div id="newDiv"&gt; world &lt;/div&gt;').text();
//just being verbose.
    var elem = $(html);
    //the actual work
    elem.appendTo("#parentDiv");
    //elem.remove();
```

a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egj8r/) uncomment the elem.remove()  lin to watch it work.

Comment: I'm following the green-checked answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437352/jquery-append-html-string-as-html/8437392#8437392 because the HTML is encoded. It seems to be perfectly valid once its decoded (it appends just fine).    Is that not correct?

Comment: You put your id in the wrong place. should be `&lt;div id="newDiv"&gt; hello &lt;/div&gt;`

Comment: edited with the html decode option you wanted.  tested `'&lt;div id="newDiv"&gt; world &lt;div id="innerDiv"&gt;!&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;'` too.

Answer (score 0):

Works great as soon as you put the id at the right place :

```
var myString = '&lt;div id="newDiv"&gt; hello &lt;/div&gt;';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NN9v2/1/