# jQuery 'HTML function doesn't work with special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass the string `"{<A+_2OF3_MSF}"` to jQuery's HTML function. It doesn't work because of special character `<`. I tried encoding/escaping an HTML tag using this escapeHtml function, but I am facing another issue after that.

```
var escapeHtml = function(theString) {
            return theString.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
        };
```

It appends HTML-encoded string as text, not as HTML. I saw the below Stack Overflow post, but then it suggests to decode it after encoding. If I do that I am back to square one.

*[Appending HTML-encoded string as HTML, not as text](http://http:/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437352/appending-html-encoded-string-as-html-not-as-text)*

I have created a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1aktfzm8/

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use `text`, not `html`.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks! I tried that but it doesn't work for me.  I have a .css('someClass').html(formattedData) .appendTo(container); text() function doesn't fit here. I am getting error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").html("<span id=\"span\"> {A+_\"2OF3_MSF\"} </span>");
        $('#span').text();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Change content of all p elements</button>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me . I have a .css('someClass').html(formattedData)
                    .appendTo(container);   text() function doesn't fit here. I am getting error.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: string could be a html  <span> {A+_2OF3_MSF} </span>. Will text() work?

Comment: YES! why not?  check edit. also if there's any additional quotes in that string then you need to escape it by putting a backslash `\\` before it.

Comment: @siam `.text()` will remove HTML tags and HTML entities I believe.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio: No; it will just set the text to whatever you pass.

Comment: @SLaks somehow this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vf252sa/) seems to remove the `span` tags though.

Comment: @Siam - I can't use text. I want html at the end which can be rendered as html and not as plain text. I would expect the output of your fiddle to be just {A+_"2OF3_MSF"}  not <span> {A+_"2OF3_MSF"} </span>

Comment: @user911 oh..then you need to set an id for the span. see update ^

Answer (score 3):

This code is working normally: https://jsfiddle.net/kilotonna/eg4be1gr/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").html("{<A+_2OF3_MSF}".replace(/</g, '&lt;'));
    });
});
```